# Where can I get the stock Android Kernel  configuration for Galaxy S3 running ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, kernel, settings

Question: We are trying to find the kernel configuration on a currently running Samsung Galaxy S2, with Android 4.0.3 (Ice-Cream Sandwich). We do not wish to root the phone. We checked `/proc/config.gz` as well as looking for `config-*` under `/boot` (which did not exist). We have downloaded the Samsung kernel git repository and are browsing arm configs. What is the kernel config that matches our phone. If it is not one of these which one will work with out phone? What is the specific configuration for the kernel?

**Specifications:**

Build Number: IML74K.UGLD3

Kernel version: 3.0.15-I9100MUGLD3-CL377577se.infra@SEP-74#3

`ls samsung/arch/arm/configs`(running on the computer we downloaded the repository on)

```
acs5k_defconfig
acs5k_tiny_defconfig
afeb9260_defconfig
ag5evm_defconfig
am200epdkit_defconfig
ap4evb_defconfig
assabet_defconfig
at91cap9adk_defconfig
at91rm9200_defconfig
at91sam9260ek_defconfig
at91sam9261_defconfig
at91sam9263_defconfig
at91sam9g20ek_defconfig
at91sam9rlek_defconfig
at91x40_defconfig
badge4_defconfig
bcmring_defconfig
cam60_defconfig
cerfcube_defconfig
cm_x2xx_defconfig
cm_x300_defconfig
cns3420vb_defconfig
colibri_pxa270_defconfig
colibri_pxa300_defconfig
collie_defconfig
corgi_defconfig
cpu9260_defconfig
cpu9g20_defconfig
da8xx_omapl_defconfig
davinci_all_defconfig
dove_defconfig
ebsa110_defconfig
edb7211_defconfig
em_x270_defconfig
ep93xx_defconfig
eseries_pxa_defconfig
exynos4_defconfig
ezx_defconfig
footbridge_defconfig
fortunet_defconfig
g3evm_defconfig
g4evm_defconfig
h3600_defconfig
h5000_defconfig
h7201_defconfig
h7202_defconfig
hackkit_defconfig
herring_defconfig
imote2_defconfig
integrator_defconfig
iop13xx_defconfig
iop32x_defconfig
iop33x_defconfig
ixp2000_defconfig
ixp23xx_defconfig
ixp4xx_defconfig
jornada720_defconfig
kirkwood_defconfig
ks8695_defconfig
lart_defconfig
loki_defconfig
lpd270_defconfig
lubbock_defconfig
mackerel_defconfig
magician_defconfig
mainstone_defconfig
mini2440_defconfig
mmp2_defconfig
msm_defconfig
mv78xx0_defconfig
mx1_defconfig
mx21_defconfig
mx27_defconfig
mx3_defconfig
mx51_defconfig
mxs_defconfig
neponset_defconfig
netwinder_defconfig
netx_defconfig
nhk8815_defconfig
nuc910_defconfig
nuc950_defconfig
nuc960_defconfig
omap1_defconfig
omap2plus_defconfig
orion5x_defconfig
palmz72_defconfig
pcm027_defconfig
pcontrol_g20_defconfig
pleb_defconfig
pnx4008_defconfig
pxa168_defconfig
pxa255-idp_defconfig
pxa3xx_defconfig
pxa910_defconfig
qil-a9260_defconfig
raumfeld_defconfig
realview_defconfig
realview-smp_defconfig
rpc_defconfig
s3c2410_defconfig
s3c6400_defconfig
s5p64x0_defconfig
s5pc100_defconfig
s5pv210_defconfig
sam9_l9260_defconfig
shannon_defconfig
shark_defconfig
simpad_defconfig
spear3xx_defconfig
spear6xx_defconfig
spitz_defconfig
stamp9g20_defconfig
tct_hammer_defconfig
tegra_defconfig
trizeps4_defconfig
u300_defconfig
u8500_defconfig
usb-a9260_defconfig
versatile_defconfig
vexpress_defconfig
viper_defconfig
xcep_defconfig
zeus_defconfig
```

Comment: That question sounds like it would get a better answer at http://stackoverflow.com as opposed to here.  This site is geared towards questions about using Android.

Comment: I am fine with the question. Some experienced users may want to compile their own kernel. Also I am not sure if it's good fit for SO.

Comment: It's also useful information on its own. For example to see if netfilter modules required for droidwall are included and so on

Answer (score 1):

Recently helped someone figure this out for another device, and the same method will probably work here:

grep all of the configs for CONFIG_ANDROID to select only those configs that enable the various android kernel customizations.  Rule out any that have substantially fewer matching lines than others.

Then examine those that match (hopefully only a very few) to see which mention Samsung, or the codename of the device or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://opensource.samsung.com? There is usually a readme file in the zip that will yield the clue :)

Also, is it CDMA/4G/LTE/GSM version? And the specific model name? those two are important to ascertain before downloading the right source from Samsung's site :)

I downloaded GT-I900P_ICS_Opensource.zip from there and the config file was u1_nfc_defconfig in arch/arm/configs. However I realized I downloaded the wrong version as the clue is in the existing Kernel version - 3.0.15-***I9100M***.... which is the GT-I9100M is what you're looking for :)